# Using Deployer on Windows to deploye laravel app

Tags: php, laravel, windows, ubuntu, php-deployer

i installed "deployer" for laravel app and i configurate it and i followed the documentation exactly like it is , worked on linux but on windows i get an error Permission denied

when i try to run this commande

```
vendor/bin/dep deploy
```

i get this **error**

> The command "touch /var/www/projectname/.dep/deploy.lock" failed.
>
> Exit Code: 1 (General error)
>
> mux_client_request_session: read from master failed: Connection reset
> by peer ControlSocket C:\Users\Dell/.ssh/deployer_user@app.server.co
> already exists, disabling multiplexing touch: cannot touch
> '/var/www/projectname/.dep/deploy.lock': Permission denied

[image]

Comment: Check your file permissions